# How to check for errors before inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, insert

I want to write several queries to DB for saving 5 users. But before saving them all i must be sure about errors. For example, i inserted the first user, and no errors. But after trying to save the second one, there were errors (NOTE: not only duplicating errors). After, i have to cancel all data i saved, and delete the first one from DB. It is bad idea, better to check for errors SOMEHOW, and after save all 3 users...

QUESTION: How to check for errors before inserting data.

NOTE: It is not enough to check wether data exists, because another errors can appear.

Comment: What kind of errors do you expect?

Comment: Problem is solved, i was expecting any kind of errors while inserting

Answer (score 3):

Consider wrapping your queries in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are transactions. This way, you send all the statements to the server, which are then executed in something that is similar to a sandbox, the server checks for errors and then (if there are none!) it saves the data.

This can be done in MySQL by wrapping your statements in:

```
BEGIN;
YOUR QUERIES GO HERE
COMMIT;
```

For more detailed information, you can have a look at [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html). Take note that not all MySQL engines support transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a **transaction** to commit all changes to the database at once? Then if any of them fail, all will be rolled back.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a transaction here for safer insertions into your database.

DB TABLE: `users having 3 fields u_id  int , u_name  varchar, u_email   varchar`

```
<?php
$dbh = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db_user", "password", "databse_name");
mysqli_autocommit($dbh, FALSE);

// run query 1
$query1 = "INSERT INTO users (u_name,u_email) VALUES('Abdus Samad1', 'abdul.samad1@...')";
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query1);
if ($result !== TRUE) {
    mysqli_rollback($dbh);  // if error, roll back transaction
}

// run query 2
$query2 = "INSERT INTO users (u_name,u_email) VALUES('Abdus Samad2', abdul.samad2@...)";
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query2);
if ($result !== TRUE) {
  mysqli_rollback($dbh); // if error, roll back transaction
  echo "Error found in one of queries";
}
else{
  echo "Success";
}

// assuming no errors, commit transaction
mysqli_commit($dbh);

// close connection
mysqli_close($dbh);
?>
```